# JavaMail not working in OSGI(ServiceMix/Karaf)

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf

I created a Karaf Instance on a Service Mix(7.0.1) and deployed my bundles into it.

The camel route is starting up properly, but always fails when it should send an email.

With the following exception:

```
javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed;
```

I tried several solutions i found from different sources around the web, but cannot actually fix it.

I tried commenting javax.activation out in the jre.properties file of the instance, as well as using a bundle that contains java mail and the osgi friendly version of the activation bundle in the same feature.

Could openJDK be an issue here?

Note: Everything works perfectly fine on a windows/oraclejdk environment, the exception only occurs in a linux/openjdk environment.

Comment: Does it work in Linux / Oracle JDK?

Comment: That's what i will try next

Comment: That was not working either, so the culprit is not the openjdk.

Comment: Thx.. can you provide a sample project? This might be a bug in camel

Comment: The issue was in fact related to class loader problems and i fixed it today. I am not entirely sure why the fix did not need to be applied on the windows environment though.

Answer (score 0):

My issue stemed from a class loader problem after all and i fixed it by bundling javax.mail/mail/1.4.7 and org.apache.servicemix.specs.activation-api-1.1/2.8.0 in the same bundle.

I also needed to remove every occurence of javax.activation from the jre.properties and config.properties file of the child instance.

I am not sure why it ran per default on a different environment, as in theory the same classloader problems should have occured too, but that might be connected to different JREs being in use.